# Rotate textbox with mouse

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a textbox in a wpf user control that shows in a popup when I click the screen. I am trying to make it so the user can grab the corner of the textbox or usercontrol and rotate it with the mouse.

The point of the control is I have added some drawing tools to a map component and this is so the user can add text to the map. I would like it if while entering the text when the textbox pops up they could also rotate the textbox with the mouse.

```
<Popup Grid.Row="1"   
           Name="_drawText"
           DataContext="{Binding Path=MapControlViewModel}"
           IsOpen="{Binding IsTextDrawingSelected, Mode=OneWay}"
           PopupAnimation="None"  
           AllowsTransparency="True"                    
           Placement="Mouse">
            <map:TextBoxDrawingControl DataContext="{Binding TextBoxDrawingControlViewModel}"/>
    </Popup>
```

Any ideas? I have seen stuff like this in drawing tools where you can select an item and rotate it.

Comment: I don't have time for a full-blown answer, but take a look at [RotateTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.rotatetransform(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea would be to add a [`Thumb`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.thumb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to your control, and modify a [`RotateTransform`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.rotatetransform%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) accordingly.  Thumb contains DragStarted, DragDelta, and DragCompleted events, which you can use to obtain an angle of rotation.

Ideally you would make the `TextBox` itself a part of the Thumb's template -- that way, you can apply the rotate-transform directly to the `Thumb.RenderTransform`, which will then rotate the TextBox along with the Thumb itself.

**Edit** Here is a hastily-cobbled together example.

UserControl XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Test.RotatableUserControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
    <Thumb DragDelta="OnDragDelta" DragCompleted="OnDragCompleted" DragStarted="OnDragStarted">
        <Thumb.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Thumb">
                <Border Padding="5" Background="DarkGray" Cursor="ScrollAll">
                    <TextBox  Text="hello" />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Thumb.Template>
    </Thumb>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Code-behind:

```
public partial class RotatableUserControl : UserControl
{
    private Point _center;

    public RotatableUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void OnDragStarted(object sender, DragStartedEventArgs e)
    {
        var thumb = (Thumb)sender;
        _center = new Point(thumb.ActualWidth/2, thumb.ActualHeight/2);
        thumb.RenderTransform = (thumb.RenderTransform as RotateTransform) ?? new RotateTransform(0, _center.X, _center.Y);
    }
    public void OnDragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        var thumb = (Thumb)sender;
        var pos = Mouse.GetPosition(thumb);
        var rotate = (RotateTransform)thumb.RenderTransform;
        double angle = Math.Atan((pos.X-_center.X) / (pos.Y-_center.Y));
        rotate.Angle += angle;
    }
    public void OnDragCompleted(object sender, DragCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var thumb = (Thumb)sender;
    }
}
```